# Question about unique pointer of classes (initialisation of variables in .h VS in constructor)

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, instantiation, unique-ptr

i'm a begginer starting with unique pointer `unique_ptr` and I have a question about them :

If I've got a class `A` and inside it's .h I have an other class `B` like this :

```
class A{

   B b;

public:

   A();
}
```

(consider the includes)

If I want to create an `unique_ptr` of `A` what is the difference for `B` in **those cases** :

(`unique_ptr<A> a = make_unique<A>()`)

**Case 1 :**

```
class A{

   B b = b(1);

public:

   A();
}
```

**and Case 2 :**

```
class A{

   B b;

public:

   A();
}
```

inside the constructor of A() :

```
A::A() {
   b = b(1);
}
```

It seem to be different for the use of `B` inside `A` for each of them, but I can't see why.

Comment: The implementation of `A` won't change just because someone else creates a `unique_ptr<A>`.  I'm not sure what you're getting at here.

Comment: @TimRoberts It's more about B , what could be the difference with it If I try to use it with A (like A->getB().doStuff() or anything with the use of B from A)

Comment: Read my answer.  The implementation of A does not change.  A does not know.  `b` is private, so no one outside of the class an use it anyway.

Comment: Should the instances of `b(1)` actually be `B(1)`?

Answer (score 2):

In case 1, when `A` is constructed, it directly initializes `A::b` with 1.

In case 2, when `A` is constructed, it first default-initializes `A::b`, and then assigns it another `B` object that is initialized with 1.

This is *no effect whatsoever* on how `unique_ptr` or `make_unique()` operate.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of c++ is different than constructor in other OOP language.
It's separate in 2 part.

- member initialization .
- function body.

---

```
#include <iostream>
struct BB{
    int num;
    BB(int in):num{in}
    {
        std::cout << "ctor BB value=" << num <<"\n";
    }
};
struct AA{
    BB b{1};
    AA()
    {
        b = BB{2};
    }

};
struct AB{
    BB b{1};//default initialization
    AB():b{2}//member initialization
    {
      //function body
    }

};

int main() {
   std::cout << "-- create AA \n";
   AA a{};
   std::cout << "value AA.b.num=" << a.b.num << "\n";
   std::cout << "-- create AB \n";
   AB b{};
   std::cout << "value AB.b.num=" << b.b.num << "\n";
}
```

result is

```
-- create AA 
ctor BB value=1
ctor BB value=2
value AA.b.num=2
-- create AB 
ctor BB value=2
value AB.b.num=2
```